# How can I get all states of children from parent element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How can I get all states of children from parent element?

I created a page, and there are a few elements, the most important is this component list.

**Here is the parent element:**

```
const Home = () => {
    const walls = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    return (
        <Layout>
                {walls.map(wall => {
                    return <Wall key={wall} index={wall} />;
                })}
        </Layout>
    );
};
```

As you can see, it generates a list of elements with map.

So, how can I get all children states from parent element?

**This is the child component:**

```
const Wall = ({ index }: IWall) => {
    const { doors, windows, handleWindows, handleDoors } = 
    useWall();

    return (
        <div>
            <input .../>
            <input .../>
            ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

**And it's hooks:**

```
export const useWall = () => {
    const [doors, setDoors] = useState(0);
    const [windows, setWindows] = useState(0);

    const handleWindows = (value: number) => {
        if (value < 0 || value > 50) return;

        setWindows(value);
    };

    const handleDoors = (value: number) => {
        if (value < 0 || value > 50) return;

        setDoors(value);
    };


    return { doors, windows, handleWindows, handleDoors };
};
```

Comment: The general solution to "Parent needs X from child" is invariably to apply the [Lifting State up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) pattern. In other words, if the parent component needs to know the state then ***it*** should be the component holding the state and passes it down to children components. What *specifically* do you need from the children components? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @DrewReese I was looking for a way without implementing all this in parent component. Well, I have two states, "windows" and "doors", in each child component. I have to get them when all children filled it's states. They are filled when user types in input elements, did you get it? But I really think I'll have to change it all to parent component, so it can manage all these states.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good plan. The alternative involves forwarding React refs so the parent components can "reach into" the children, but this flows counter to just about everything React is designed for and is more of an escape hatch. It would also still require some "state" in the parent to keep tabs on all the children (*i.e. all those refs that need to be forwarded*), which is arguably more moving parts doing what they aren't really supposed to do anyway.

Comment: TBH there wouldn't be that much all that different. If you'd like I could provide an example.

Comment: Ok, I get it! Yes, of course, I really appreciate if you could provide this, but no worries at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally considered a React anti-pattern for parent components to reach into children components to access state and functions. The solution is to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent component and pass the state and state update callbacks as props ***down*** to children components.

Example:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [walls, setWalls] = useState<IWall[]>(
    [1, 2, 3, 4].map((id) => ({
      id,
      doors: 0,
      windows: 0
    }))
  );

  const changeHandler = (id: number) => (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    if (Number(value) >= 0 && Number(value) <= 50) {
      setWalls((walls) =>
        walls.map((wall) =>
          wall.id === id ? { ...wall, [name]: value } : wall
        )
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      {walls.map((wall) => {
        return (
          <Wall
            key={wall.id}
            wall={wall}
            changeHandler={changeHandler(wall.id)}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

...

```
interface IWall {
  id: number;
  doors: number;
  windows: number;
}

interface WallProps {
  wall: IWall;
  changeHandler: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement>;
}

const Wall = ({ changeHandler, wall }: WallProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Wall: {wall.id}</h2>
      <label>
        Doors
        <input
          name="doors"
          type="number"
          value={wall.doors}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Windows
        <input
          name="windows"
          type="number"
          value={wall.windows}
          onChange={changeHandler}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit adoring-khayyam-3sd3udhow-can-i-get-all-states-of-children-from-parent-element]

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot dude! It's really clarified now, God bless you! :D